# JOOQ How to do UNION and WHERE IN

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I'm using `org.jooq.impl.Executor` to create a query that I want to pass to `JdbcOperations`. I'm passing parameter values by using `.where(Condition...)`.

After chaining methods for the executor, I get a `Query` object. The problem is when I call `query.getSQL()`, the returned query string contains parameters `?,?,?` instead of my inserted values.

This is the code I'm using to build the SQL query.
Note that `TableA` has three foreign keys to `TableB`. I tried to use `JOIN ON` with `OR` to join `TableA` and `TableB` but the performance was too slow.

```
Query query = executor.select(fieldsToSelect)
    .from("TableA")
    .join("TableB").on("TableA.FirstForeignKey = TableB.TableBID")
    .join("TableC")
    .on("TableC.TableCID = TableB.TableCForeignKey")
    .where(condition)
    .union(executor.select(fieldsToSelect)
            .from("TableA")
            .join("TableB").on("TableA.SecondForeignKey = TableB.TableBID")
            .join("TableC")
            .on("TableC.TableCID = TableB.TableCForeignKey")
            .where(condition)
            .union(executor.select(fieldsToSelect)
                    .from("TableA")
                    .join("TableB").on("TableA.ThirdForeignKey = TableB.TableBID")
                    .join("TableC")
                    .on("TableC.TableCID = TableB.TableCForeignKey")
                    .where(condition)));
```

This is how I create `Condition` object for the executor:

```
MySQLFactory.fieldByName(Integer.class, TABLE_NAME_TABLEA, "TableAID")
                .in(ArrayUtils.toObject(ids));
```

This is how I perform the query:

```
jdbcOperations.query(query.getSQL(),query.getBindValues().toArray(), myMapper);
```

How can I correctly map parameters with values and use the query with `JdbcOperations`?

Comment: Hmm, `Executor` and `JdbcOperations`... That is a rather old version of jOOQ, isn't it? What version is this?

Comment: The project has 3.0.0-RC2 version of JOOQ

Comment: Huh, I knew it. The `Executor` type had been around only while developing jOOQ 3.0, not in the final release. You should definitely upgrade! Anyway, I'll give you an answer that I think would have worked with your version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the [`Query.getSQL()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL--) method returns a query with bind variables (`?`). You'll then pass that SQL string to a `PreparedStatement` and bind the variables individually, extracting them first via [`Query.getBindValue()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getBindValues--)

An alternative version of the [`Query.getSQL(boolean)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-boolean-) or [`Query.getSQL(ParamType)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-org.jooq.conf.ParamType-) method will indicate to jOOQ that the bind variables should be inlined into the SQL string, in order to form a static SQL statement, not a prepared statement.

You can also tell jOOQ to generate all SQL statements as static statements by using `StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT` on the `Settings` that you provide the jOOQ `Configuration` with.

This is all documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/